# wcf rest service message logging

Tags: c#, wcf, filtering, trace

I need to add [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967569%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for WCF REST service. Something like this:

```xml
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="false"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" >
    <filters>
      <add>any XPath</add>
    </filters>
  </messageLogging>
```

But no matter what I pass as XPath string - result is always the same: filtering is not applied. Maybe I should add message version data in "filter" tag(`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none"` and `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"` in my case)?

I tried to do it, but unsuccessfully. Maybe somebody can help? I can't find any useful information about  filtering implementation in WCF REST services.

Comment: See Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731308.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How are you specifying the filter? I'm not sure it's as simple as a string?

```
<messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
    logMalformedMessages="true" 
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
    maxMessagesToLog="420">
    <filters>
        **<add nodeQuota="10" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                 /soap:Envelope/soap:Header
        </add>**
     </filters>
</messageLogging>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that filter you suggested describe soap envelope. Im my case I have to deal with REST service.